# UILabel shows in iOS simulator, but not after running .IPA app on device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, uilabel

"iLabel" shows in the simulator, but once archived and the IPA file is run, it fails to show. I tried cleaning the code, but that didn't do anything. The idea of the iLabel is to show when the UIIndicator is animating, and of course disappear when the indicator disappears.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [[self myTableView] setDelegate:self];
  [[self myTableView] setDataSource:self];
  array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  [self startActivity];
}

-(void)startActivity
{
  indicator.hidden=NO;
  [indicator startAnimating];

  [self uploadData];
  NSLog(@"VIEWDIDLOAD-INDICATOR-TURNING-ON: %@", indicator);
}

-(void)uploadData
{
  NSLog(@"Uploading...");

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkForReachability) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

  Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
  [reachability startNotifier];

  NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

  if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
  {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Oops..."
                          message: @"Network connection lost."
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];    }

  else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
  {
    iLabel.text = @"Please be patient...";
  }
}


- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  [self setString];

  NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
  NSString *string1 = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
  NSString *string7 = [dic objectForKey:@"review_count"];
  NSString *string3 = [dic objectForKey:@"display_phone"];
  NSDictionary *location = [dic objectForKey:@"location"];
  NSArray *array2 = [location objectForKey:@"display_address"];
  NSDictionary *coordinate = [location objectForKey:@"coordinate"];

  lat = [coordinate objectForKey:@"latitude"];
  lon = [coordinate objectForKey:@"longitude"];
  mURL = [dic objectForKey:@"mobile_url"];

  NSString *string4 = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *string5 = [array2 objectAtIndex:1];
  NSString *img2String = [dic objectForKey:@"image_url"];

for (NSDictionary *diction in dic)
{
    NSString *string6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yelp Rating:                   "];
    NSString *string8 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Based on %@ Review(s)", string7];

    [array addObject:string1];
    [array addObject:string6];
    [array addObject:string8];
    [array addObject:string3];
    [array addObject:string4];
    [array addObject:string5];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:img2String]]];
    imageView.image = image;
  }

  for (NSDictionary *diction in coordinate)
  {
    [array addObject:lat];
    [array addObject:lon];
  }

  [[self myTableView] reloadData];

  [indicator stopAnimating];
  indicator.hidden=YES;
  [indicator removeFromSuperview];

  iLabel.text = @"";
  [iLabel removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Posting some code would be helpful...

Comment: Do you happen to have a weak reference to iLabel? I can't tell just from the code you posted, but I have seen it before where removing and then adding a UI element that has a weak reference will work on devices and the simulator, but once it is optimized (like in a release/archive build) the memory is released more aggressively and things disappear faster. You can test this by changing your reference to be strong, and if that fixes it try to re-work what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't catch it earlier. The problem was in the following:

```
    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Oops..."
                          message: @"Network connection lost."
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];    }

    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
      ilabel.text = @"Please be patient...";
    }
```

I changed the bottom portion to:

```
    else
    {
      ilabel.text = @"Please be patient...";
    }
```

...and everything is now good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the code you posted, if the remote host isn't reachable, you never set the text of `iLabel`. So, if the label doesn't show up on the device, check that the remote host is reachable from the device *at the time you set up the label*.

Comment: I just thought of another possibility: I declared iLabel only in my ".M" interface. I'm thinking if I add it to ".H", retain and synthesize I might have better results?